# [].forEach.call alternative in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have code written in javascript and I want to converted to jQuery

Just one line that I can't figure

```
[].forEach.call($('p'),function(i) {
```

I tried each()

```
$('p').each(function(i) {
```

But Its not working at all

If you want to see the code in action, help me to converted
http://jsfiddle.net/e5qST/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Read the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/each/)

```
.each( function(index, Element) )
```

The first argument is the index, the second is the element. So you are trying to read the style of a number.

You can just use `this` or the second argument inside the function which will reference the current element in the set that is being looped.

```
$('p').each(function(i){
    var fZ = 30;
    while(fZ > 6 && this.scrollHeight > this.offsetHeight) {
        fZ--;
        this.style.fontSize = fZ+'px';
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:-

```
$('p').each(function(index, item) {
```

Working [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/e5qST/)

Comment: What is the world does that do?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('p').each(function(index, e){
    var fZ = 30;
    while(fZ > 6 && e.scrollHeight > e.offsetHeight) {
        fZ--;
        e.style.fontSize = fZ+'px';
    }
});
```

Works in the fiddle